# Hot water heater and gas-stove not working at the same time

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, gas, stove, natural-gas

So I have a gas water heater and a gas stove. I was able to cook on my stove this morning at around 8 a.m. and then I took a shower and it was not  hot. I tried to light the pilot on the water heater, it ignited but then went right out.
I tried to light the stove again and I hear no hissing of gas coming through the burners.
So I called out the gas company. He came and checked the hoses inside the house and there coming through the hoses on both appliances. It's your Regulators the it said. The question is why did both Regulators on the gas stove and the gas water heater go out at the exact same time? That's too much of a coincidence for it to be random.  I don't want to go replace all these parts when I   find out that it's not my problem it's the gas company's with having something wrong with the line.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the gas pressure regulator is near where the gas line first enters the house. After the regulator is where the gas line will split off to go to your appliance.

When the gas company person said the regulator was bad they were referring to this common regulator. It's going bad is why it affected both of your appliances.

Comment: Does the gas company replace that or does the customer?+1

Comment: @JACK - It really depends upon where the gas company considers the demarcation point between the utility and the dwelling. If it is an integrated regulator with the gas usage meter included in the same unit then in all probability if falls to the utility to replace a faulty regulator. But in the end the OP would really need to talk to their utility personnel.

Comment: Each appliance also has a regulator. If debris/condensate came down the line it could have affected multiple appliances at the same time, yet had nothing to do with the main gas-supply regulator (which should be the property of the utility company/entity).